# Extract information from a file and add it as columns to another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, paste

I have this file(test.txt) :

```
###########
###########
1x1 1y1
1x2 1y2
###########
###########
2x1 2y1
2x2 2y2
###########
###########
3x1 3y1
3x2 3y2
```

> 1x1, 1x2, 1Y1 , 1Y2 , etc .. represent decimal , positive and negative
>   numerical quantities
>
> #
>   
>   # Correspond to text and numbers headers are values ​​that do not want to process. Each containing 9 lines that begin with numbers
>
> or letters.

and I want to generate this output file(output.txt) using pipes:

```
 1x1 1y1 2x1 2y1 3x1 3y1
 1x2 1y2 2x2 2y2 3x2 3y2
```

try:(test.sh)

```
touch output.txt

paste -d' ' output.txt <(sed '5,12d' test.txt | sed '1,2d' | awk '{print $1" "$2}') > output.txt
paste -d' ' output.txt <(sed '9,12d' test.txt | sed '1,6d' | awk '{print $1" "$2}') > output.txt
paste -d' ' output.txt <(sed '1,10d' test.txt | awk '{print $1" "$2}') > output.txt
```

Result:
cat output.txt

```
3x1 3y1
3x2 3y2
```

I'm doing wrong in my script?

**I forgot to mention that the test.txt file actually have 1,000,000 rows . Therefore , I would like to do this efficiently. I resolved this problem by using auxiliary files however, the performance was very slow. That's why I want to do without use of auxiliary files.**

Regards

Comment: You use the file output.txt both for read and write in the same command, then it erases the content each time. With different filenames each time, it works (even it's not a good solution)

Answer (score 1):

```
paste <(grep "^1x" test.txt)  <(grep "^2x" test.txt) <(grep "^3x" test.txt)
1x1 1y1 2x1 2y1 3x1 3y1
1x2 1y2 2x2 2y2 3x2 3y2
```

*EDIT:* use this as skeleton (no need to call `paste` 3 times):

```
paste <(grep <your_regex_1> test.txt) \
      <(grep <your_regex_2> test.txt) \
      <(grep <your_regex_3> test.txt)
```

Comment: This good response to the particular case . However , 1x1 1x2, etc .. represent variables , may be any numerical value .
#### Contains letters and numbers .

Only simplify the file , sorry for not putting more details.

Comment: The idea is that you can generate the output by calling `paste` one time only. Just insert your personal regexp rules in each of the three process substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

If there are always two columns of numbers in the input so you always have two rows of output:

```
awk 'NF==2 {row1=row1 $0 " "; getline; row2=row2 $0 " "} END {print row1; print row2}' test.txt
```

Output:

```
1x1 1y1 2x1 2y1 3x1 3y1 
1x2 1y2 2x2 2y2 3x2 3y2
```

If the `####` lines might have two fields, you will have to adjust the target `NF==2` to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^\S+ \S+/N;//H;$!d;x;s/.//;:a;s/^([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/\1 \3\n\2 \4/;ta' file
```

This saves the required data in the hold space then uses pattern matching to build the required output.